# Everything in header gets smaller when viewport width gets smaller. How do I change this?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website where I have a banner with a logo in the left corner and a british flag in the right corner (added with the img element). I have specified the heights of the both images (both of them are svg), and the heights of the images look good while the window is bigger than 970px. When the window gets smaller than 970px both images shrinks as well. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I have changed the logo to a png with the same result, and even when adding text the text shrinks even though it has a specified font-size, which does not happen in the main, aside or footer. I have also tried with another css style sheet with which another document did not have the same problem (although this style sheet was not adapted to fit the html-document I was working in at the moment) but the outcome with my current document was the same.

```
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, .8);
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav ul li {
  flex: none;
}
```

I expected the images to stay the same size when the window rezised, but they also resized with the window.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle about your problem so we can reproduce it and play around with it in order to fix it?

Comment: Sure, I'm new to all this so will it be ok without the actual images? I don't know how to add them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a viewport meta tag to your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag